# firefox div with overflow hides the characters on te right

Tags: firefox, text, overflow, hidden

I have an issue with the right part of the text in a div being hidden when the scrollbar is shown!

No problem with IE, but with Firefox or Chrome.

[image]

Does someone already seen this issue, and possibly have a fix?

Comment: This shouldn't normally happen, unless there are styles that go out of their way to make the text overflow.  Can you link to an actual testcase showing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using some css properties like margin-right or word-break...

eg:

```
margin-right:10px;
```

or

```
word-break: break-all;
```

This might work...